# MonoGame/XNA rotating an image

Tags: c#, xna, sprite, monogame, image-rotation

This code is to draw the tower. Square locations are the top left of the square. TILE_SIZE is simply the dimensions of the square.

```
SpriteBatch.Draw(TowerImage, new Rectangle(square.X * TILE_SIZE, square.Y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE), null, Color.White, myTower.Rotation, 
    new Vector2(TILE_SIZE - 35, TILE_SIZE - 35), SpriteEffects.None, (float)0.0);
```

This code is how I determine the rotation

```
public void FaceTarget(Vector2 center, Vector2 enemyCenter)
        {
            Vector2 direction = center - enemyCenter;
            direction.Normalize();

            this.Rotation = (float)Math.Atan2(-direction.X, direction.Y);
        }
```

I did this based on:

http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/Rotation.php

http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/Direction_to_Angle.php

The rotation is being really weird, here is how it looks normally:

[image: http://puu.sh/bkd0E.png]

But when it rotates it goes like this:

[image: http://puu.sh/bkd6K.png]

Finally when it looks down, it goes complete off path, it's not rotating by its center, but the entire image is moving why is it doing that?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PuiZ.jpg]

Only the first image is actually the tower in the correct position

It seems like it is rotating of the top left point and I don't know why. Can anyone help?

Comment: did you tried `Vector2(sprite.width/2,sprite.height/2)` for origin ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, your sprite is taking into consideration as the origin of rotation a `Vector2.Zero` (or `Vector2(0,0)`) point. That means the upper left point of the `Texture2D` file.

I see that you are setting the origin in the `Draw` method to `TILE_SIZE - 35` which makes me wonder, is the tile a square of 70 pixels W/H?

What happens if you replace the substraction with `new Vector2(TowerImage.Width / 2, TowerImage.Height / 2)`?

I'll leave you an example from [this site](http://circlessuck.blogspot.ch/2012/01/xna-tutorial-sprite-rotation.html) which explains easily how to rotate an image following the mouse position at all times:

**Update method:**

```
MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();
mousePosition = new Vector2(mouse.X, mouse.Y);

Vector2 direction = mousePosition - position;
direction.Normalize();

rotation = (float)Math.Atan2(
              (double)direction.Y, 
              (double)direction.X);
```

**Draw method:**

```
spriteBatch.Begin();

spriteBatch.Draw(
     rocket,
     position,
     null,
     Color.White,
     rotation,
     new Vector2(
         rocket.Width / 2, 
         rocket.Height / 2),
     1.0f,
     SpriteEffects.None,
     1.0f);

spriteBatch.End();
```

Check that in the posted code the rotation angle is calculated slightly different than yours, but the important piece of code is the calculation of the origin point in the `Draw` method.

Comment: I will definitely try that. Also, the TILE_SIZE is equal to the textures of the path and grass, it's 40 px, for some reason if I do TILE_SIZE - 35 it puts it around the center of the tile, even if I do -TILE_SIZE or something it puts it really far away. But yes, it is rotating around the top left corner and I don't know why. Even after adjustments it is a huge rotation that is becoming difficult to control. I will try that tutorial tomorrow.

Comment: Great, let me know if that doesn't help and I'll try it on my home PC :)

Comment: Thank you! The ImageWidth/2 worked, how was I so stupid.. I tried moving it's origin, etc... It never worked

Comment: Congrats! Happy I was of help :)